# Can a control be used as the switch variable in a Select...Case in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a function that handles events from a number of buttons and trying to define a Select...Case based on the clicked button. Something like this...

```
   Private Sub btnClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles btnThis.Click, _
                btnThat.Click, _
                btnTheOther.Click
        Dim button_clicked As Button = CType(sender, Button)

        ...Do some common parts...

        Select button_clicked

            Case btnThis
                 ...Do this...

            Case btnThat
                 ...Do that...

            Case btnTheOther
                 ...Do the other...

            Case Else

        End Select
```

But I can't get it to compile; it reports that "Operator = is not defined for types 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'". I've also tried

```
Select button_clicked

    Case btnThis.Equals
```

and

```
Select button_clicked

    Case btnThis.Equals(button_clicked)
```

Which don't work either. Is there a way I can define a Select...Case in this manner or is it always destined to fail due to the attempt at comparison of reference types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the control's name is one option:

```
Private Sub btnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
            Handles btnThis.Click, _
                    btnThat.Click, _
                    btnTheOther.Click

  Select DirectCast(sender, Button).Name
    Case btnThis.Name
      ...do this...
    Case btnThat.Name
      ...do that...
    Case btnTheOther.Name
      ...do the other...
    Case Else
      ...etc
  End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [Is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex56dsed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword to compare if objects are *equal* but you have to use [If](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statements to check.

```
If sender Is btnThis Then
     ...
ElseIf sender Is btnThat Then
     ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for that; I was woefully ignorant of the Is keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Case True
    Case sender Is Button1
        MsgBox("Button One!")
    Case sender Is Button2
        MsgBox("Button Two!")
End Select
```

Comment: This does work, but it may baffle anyone who has to maintain your code. Personally I prefer to avoid this - essentially this is an `If ... ElseIf ... ElseIf ...` block masquerading as a `Select Case`. Why not write the `If ... ElseIf... ElseIf...`